# wireshark coredumps during load

Tags: linux, plugins, open-source, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have a wireshark dissector plugin.
I also have a wireshark installed from apt-get.

The wireshark loads fine without the plugin inserted in the right place.
When I include the plugin .so file and try to run wireshark, I get the following error:

```
$ wireshark
08:23:45          Err  register_subtree_array: subtree item type (ett_...) not -1 ! This is a development error: Either the subtree item type has already been assigned or was not initialized to -1.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I tried understanding the problem. It says the subtree was already assigned (I'm assuming assigned an ett value) or was not initialized with -1. there are 3 files in my plugin where the API is called and I checked the values of ett[] being supplied to the API in each of these places. They are all initialized to -1.

Stuck in a roadblock. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Also, I do not understand where wireshark dumps the core. I could not find any core.
Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you want to insert a plugin into a program, you have to ensure that the library API that the plugin was compiled against is the same as that provided by the program.

Unless wireshark provides documented versioning in its library API, this means that you have to have the plugin compiled against the same version of wireshark that you intend to use it with. So, if you compile your wireshark or the plugin yourself, you should compile the other as well. If you get your plugin in binary form, you should get your wireshark also from exactly the same place, otherwise you may not know if the two are compatible or not. If you only get a core dump when you insert the plugin, that's a strong indication that the two may not be compatible.

Comment: See my comment in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323798/how-to-debug-wireshark-plugin-using-gdb

Comment: In any case, you've now posted a question in ask.wireshark.org. http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/27721/wireshark-coredumps-during-load . I suggest that this conversation be contined at at that site since th's where you'll most likely get the best help.

Comment: The two environments are of the exact same wireshark version. Also, I would get a build error/ undefined symbol if there was a mismatch. I generally get quicker and smart responses here at stackoverflow. That's the reason I prefer to add the question here.

Comment: I agree with willyo: if you see inexplicable incompatibility between a program compiled by someone else and a plugin compiled by you, you should try compiling the program yourself, too.

Answer (score 0):

> register_subtree_array: subtree item type (ett_...) not -1

...

> there are 3 files in my plugin where the API is called and I checked the values of ett[] being supplied to the API in each of these places. They are all initialized to -1.

To which API are you referring?  You must not call `register_subtree_array()` on any particular `ett_` array more than once; if you're calling it twice, the first call will cause the `ett_` values in the array to be set to values different from -1, so the next call will fail with that error.